# Creating an eBook with search capabilities for the iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, search

I have been trying to find an answer or info related in creating an ebook for the iPhone with search capabilities of the text, and there is nothing clear. I just want to load several pages using HTML, PDF or any other way, and that is fine. The problem is to find a way to search the text on the HTML or PDF and provide a result for the user. Could anyone show me the best way to achieve this or show me a link of a BOOK or Tutorial, since I have been looking for parsers, search engines, and of course, everything is written for experts in programming. I know exactly how to use Xcode, the problem is if the only way to achieve this is to get into Java or HTML programming. Please Help!

Comment: Port the Java examples you found to Obj-C?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're looking for, but if you have iWork installed, then Pages can export a document as an ePub file, and this can be searched with iBooks.

Comment: Great idea! epub, but the question is still open, how can I search an epub document. I do not want to use iBook, since the book I am planning to develop will also have a map and other information.